# How to check input string is a valid number using jQuery - Backend Wordpress

Tags: string, input, numbers

I have tried to check if an input in a field is a valid number at Wordpress backend (ADD, EDIT post page), and if it is not, it will display a warning message. Here is what I have tried to achieve that:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      addRequiredField($);
    });
    function addRequiredField($) {
      var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");   
              if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a valid price");
              }

              //  if (isNaN(e.target.value)) {
           //  if ((!e.target.validity.valid) || isNaN(e.target.value)) {
           // if ((!e.target.validity.valid) || (/^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(e.target.value))) {

        /*      else if (isNaN(e.target.value)) {
               e.target.setCustomValidity("It is an invalid number. Please enter valid numbers like 280, 364, etc.");
              }
              else {
               return true;
              }  */
          };
          elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
          };
        }
      }
```

I have updated the above codes.

It works really well: there is a warning message as intended after pressing Publish button of Wordpress in a case nothing is entered in the price field of a form . However, the above codes dont validate the string of the price field at all. I have tried isNaN() or Regex as shown in comments (//), they dont work at all. How can I validate that price string correctly. Very appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  addRequiredField($);
});

function addRequiredField($) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("");
      if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a price");
      } else if (/\d+\.\d+/.test(e.target.value)) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("It is an invalid number. Please enter valid numbers like 280, 364, etc.");
      } else {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

It looks like there is a mistake in the code where you are checking if the entered value is a valid number. The isNaN function checks if a value is NaN (Not-a-Number), but it doesn't log anything to the console

Comment: Dear dev.skas, Thank you for prompt help. It does not work; there is no warning message.

Comment: @daro2013 can you pls check

Comment: I did test your codes. It seems not working - I think something is not right with my files - I am still investigating them. Many thanks

Comment: update: very appreciate your help, dev.skas, but your codes dont work too - I have updated my original codes so that it makes it easy for developers to help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numberString = "0123456";
const isFloat = /\d+\.\d+/.test(
    numberString
);
const checkZeroValue = /^[1-9]\d*$/.test(numberString)

if(isFloat == true ){
  console.log("float");
} else if(checkZeroValue == false){
  console.log("zero");
}else {
  console.log("numbers are correct")
}
```

Comment: Dear Smit, I have not test your codes, but it is not quite related to my issue. The input value is taken from an input in a form field. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed on another post here:

[Correct way of getting an element from an input of html form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77669979/correct-way-of-getting-an-element-from-an-input-of-html-form-using-jquery/77670886#77670886)

Here are full jQuery working codes:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      function addRequiredField($) {
        jQuery('#priceID').attr('required','required');
        
        // Warnings when no string or price is entered
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
              e.target.setCustomValidity("");
              if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                  e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a price");
              }
          };
          elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
              e.target.setCustomValidity("");
          };
        }

        // Warnings when copy and paste invalid numbers into the price field, or leading ZERO numbers like 013, 03997, etc. are input in the price field
        jQuery('#ait-opt-metabox-_ait-item_item-data-subtitle-en_US').on("keyup", function() {
          /*
            within the callback you can access $(this) to refer to the element
            and you can find the value of the input using val()
          */
          var price = $(this).val();
          var valid = /^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(price);


          if (!valid) {
           // console.log("Invalid input!");
           alert('It is invalid number')

            /* Using val() again to set the modified value */
          //  $(this).val(price.substring(0, price.length - 1));
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Here is html codes:

```
    <input type="text" id="priceID" name="price">
```

Many thanks