# Correct way of getting an element from an input of html form using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have tried to get an element called price input of an html form for jQuery without a success:

// HTML codes:

```
    <input type="text" id="priceID" name="price">
```

// jQuery codes:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      //  jquery('#priceID').on("keyup", function(){
        jquery('#priceID').on("keyup", function(){
          //  var priceStr = jquery('#priceID').val();
          var priceStr = document.getElementById('priceID');
         // var priceStr = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

            var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(priceStr),
                val = priceStr.value;
            
            if(!valid){
                console.log("Invalid input!");
                priceStr.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
            }
        });
    });
```

I use this guidance as a reference for testing the input string/value of the price field above:

[Price field validation using javascript either jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494747/price-field-validation-using-javascript-either-jquery)

I have tried the above jQuery codes for a form at Wordpress Admin backend. The html form is located somewhere in child theme. That may be an issue?

Please advise how to get the price value in a correct way.

Cheers

Comment: 1. It's not `jquery` it's `jQuery`, this small issue will make the entire thing broken.
2. You're mixing jQuery with vanilla JS, your code is very inconsistent.
3. The more i read your code the more confusing it gets, what are you trying to achieve here? You're trying to test regex on an element for some reason.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please include them in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:

I just insearted a line of code below:

```
    jQuery('#priceID').attr('required','required');
```

on top inside the function created by Professor Abronsius to get attention from my wp theme (haha), and now the string entered in the Price field can be retrieved.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      jQuery('#priceID').on("keyup", function() {
        jQuery('#priceID').attr('required','required');
        /* 
          within the callback you can access $(this) to refer to the element
          and you can find the value of the input using val()
        */
        var price = $(this).val();

        var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(price);

        if (!valid) {
          console.log("Invalid input!");

          /* Using val() again to set the modified value */
          $(this).val(price.substring(0, price.length - 1));
        }
      });
    });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with jQuery but have seen it enough to get some basic functionality working - the `keyup` callback has access to the element that triggered the event using `$(this)` and the native jQuery method `val()` can be used to both get and set the value therein.

FYI: `jquery` is spelled incorrectly!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#priceID').on("keyup", function() {
    /* 
      within the callback you can access $(this) to refer to the element
      and you can find the value of the input using val()
    */
    var price = $(this).val();

    var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(price);

    if (!valid) {
      console.log("Invalid input!");

      /* Using val() again to set the modified value */
      $(this).val(price.substring(0, price.length - 1));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="priceID" name="price">
```

Comment: Hi Professor Abronsius, wow 33.5k at stackoverflow. I use the above jQuery codes for Wordpress backend which I forgot to mention in my post. I tested yours, but they still dont produce any results. This is because they are at Wordpress backend? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is then. The above snippet appears to do what your code tried to do (ie: modify user input to remove non-numeric input) - what results do you expect your code to produce? The jQuery/JS code and the PHP/Wordpress backend are separate entities - please clarify your problem

Comment: Hi Professor Abronsius
The problem is that jquery codes above dont retrieve the value of the price field from the form input. This is very weird. Thanks

Comment: There is clearly more to your problem that the code you have shared - the above snippet works so the problem must be elsewhere. Have you used the console to look for errors? Do you have multiple elements with the same IDs?

Comment: Hi Professor Abronsius
 I can confirm your codes are working when I insert this line of codes:

Comment: jQuery('#priceID').attr('required','required');